# Protractor with Mocha/Chai don't display errors since 1.8.0 migration

Tags: gruntjs, mocha.js, protractor, chai

I'm having a lot E2E tests done with Protractor 1.3.1 / Mocha 1.21.4 and Chai 1.9.1.

Since I migrate to Protractor 1.8.0, Mocha 2.2.1, I've got no error description when a test fail. This make very hard to find what is wrong.

Example :

```
We are connected to mongo !
    Show/hide login bar :
      √ Should see the login bar
      √ Should see the loggin button
      √ Should not see the loggout button
    Account creation popup :
      √ Should see the create account form (944ms)
      √ Should not be able to submit the form
      √ Should be possible to submit the form after checking the CG (1102ms)
      √ Should not be possible to submit the form without typing email, pseudo and accountType (530ms)
      √ Should be possible to submit the form with email, pseudo and accountType (2325ms)
      √ Should be possible to create an account by submitting the form (1423ms)
      √ Should not be possible to create an account already existing and activated
    Show direct account creation popup :
      √ Should display accountCreationPopup when calling /create-account.html (1980ms)
    Exception thrown: Keeping the Selenium server alive

d:\Projets\Clouderial\nodeProjects\cld-apps\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
>>
>> Test failed but keep the grunt process alive.
```

I've tried with different Mocha reporter but without success.

Any cluse would be greatly appreciated.

Jean-Marc

Edit :
I've notice that the problem appears only when protractor is run with grunt and grunt-protractor-runner
Running protractor with grunt-protractor-runner outside Grunt works. The command is run like this :

```
node_modules/grunt-protractor-runner/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor test/protractor/e2e.conf.js
```

Same command with same config runned by grunt mask the errors.

EDIT 2 : 
The colors in Mocha reporter are not displayed when running inside Grunt and are normally displayed outside Grunt. Maybe it will give some clues to what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue for jasmine-spec-reporter and with the help of @bcaudan I think the problem has been found. What I had to do was set the `enabled` property of `colors` to `true`:

```js
var colors = require('colors');
colors.enabled = true;
```

Here is the [initial thread](https://github.com/bcaudan/jasmine-spec-reporter/issues/36) where the issue was discussed.

Here is the [thread](https://github.com/Marak/colors.js/issues/127) that shows the current fix for the issue.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.